# How to show \textnaira in the document?

Tags: textcomp

Why `\textnaira` doesn't appear in the document?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
    $\textnaira 1000$
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: What is this command?

Comment: @Bernard This macro is defined by the `textcomp` package and inserts ₦ (NAIRA SIGN, U+20A6). @liswyhy The macro `\textnaira` should not be used inside math mode. If you write `\textnaira 1000` without the `$` signs, it renders correctly.

Comment: Well, it's `\textnaira`, so you have to use it in text mode, i.e. `$\text{\textnaira} 1000$` (needs `\usepackage{amsmath}` for `\text`).

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot.